# Meaning of 地のまま

Tags: meaning, conditionals

地のままの自分でいればいい
Ji no mama no jibun de ireba ii.

What does this mean?
ji is oneself, jibun is myself, as for ireba I understand it is to accept (verb ireru)and "ba" is the conditional "if".

"地のままの自分" self in the same state myself
"いればいい" is ok to accept
so the final translation is "IT is ok to accept myself as I am" IS this translation correct?

Comment: We'd need more context to evaluate whether the translation is correct, but in the meantinme, see if the first answer [here](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1431142694) clarifies the "地のまま" for you.

Answer (score 5):

The translation isn't far off the mark, but you got two points wrong.

・The 地 ("earth") here means something (or a state of being) that is natural, unvarnished, unadorned. Hence 地のままの自分 = "one's self as it is natural"; "one's natural self".

・いれば is a conditional form of いる ("to be"), not いれる.

A literal translation:

> If one is his/her natural self, it's fine.

Pragmatically speaking, what/who the subject of 自分のままでいる is and to whom 自分 refers depend on the context -- on who is addressing this sentence to whom (if anyone). Also dependent on the context is what sort of communicative purpose it has. It can be a general statement of an idea ("It's good if people are their 
 natural selves.") or it can be a piece of advice to an angst-ridden friend ("Just be who you are. It's okay."), or it 
 can be about the speaker themselves ("I can be the natural me ,and it'll be alright."). A good practical translation should take all these factors into account, and it cannot be done without context.

Answer (score 1):

I think all of your partial interpretations are correct except for ireba.

***ireba*** is to stay, exist, be (verb ***iru*** 居る), but not ***ireru*** 入れる.

The phrase could be said for everybody including you and me according to the context.

So, the whole translation is like:
- *It is ok to be yourself as usual yourself.*
- *It is ok to be yourself without pretension.*

***地｛じ｝*** in 地のまま is ***素性｛すじょう｝*** *one's true nature* in this phrase.
***地｛じ｝*** is neither *earth* nor *ground*, but is ***素地｛そじ｝*** *material* before being colored or decorated to [look better]{LLLLLLLLLLL
}, and the meaning of ***素性｛すじょう｝*** *one's true nature* has come from the meaning of 素地.

Answer (score 0):

What's the provenance of this? "It would be good if you were to remain your own true self" looks as though it might be a translation of Polonius's words to Laertes in Hamlet: "To thine own self be true [and it shall follow as the night the day thou canst not then be false to any man]"  By the way, perhaps it's worth reiterating that である= "is"/ でいる= "continues to be", "goes on being".